# how to show alphabets in circular view Android

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I want my text view fields to show in circular form. Each Text View contains a letter

I want my output like this

```
                   A R
                 B     C
                 K     M
                   W P
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find libraries like [andreilisun/Circular-Layout](https://github.com/andreilisun/Circular-Layout) by searching online. After that, it's your choice whether to import them into your project, or to use them as reference and implement your own custom views.

Comment: actually i am implementing multiple text Views using code in a loop. There is no xml for the text view. I am unable to put those text views in circular from dynamically

Comment: You'll have to see if you can use the library programmatically then. It should be possible. Otherwise your only option is using a custom view as mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: Thanks alot. Your answer is valid and i will try to use the library and set my xml according to it. cheers

Answer (score 0):

So just create a [custom View](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components) and then [calculate where to put those letters](https://www.mathsisfun.com/polar-cartesian-coordinates.html), what's stopping you there?

Comment: actually i am implementing multiple text Views using code in a loop. There is no xml for the text view. I am unable to put those text views in circular from dynamically